# Calculate sum each row by jQuery when changing value in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

On keyup of quantity textbox, the price was changed. But sub total div doesn't change the value​, only if I refresh a page.

Any idea how to calculate sum of each row and change in `subtotal` div in jquery please.

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you need to share the related html

Comment: I'm editing my jsFiddle dear.

Comment: This is a short code of my backbone http://jsfiddle.net/qesAu/. Sorry if it is messy!

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't even run and the HTML is full of some sort of template stuff.

Comment: @muistooshort , yeah it is the template of my backbone view.

Comment: Then why isn't it in a `<script>` and why isn't the view treating it like a template and why isn't there some faked sample data driving the view?

Comment: No `script` because I used it as an html file using text! plugin, once I search, there is no need to put `<script>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a class assigned to all textfields that you want to consider for subtotal, and listen for change on those textfields and compute subtotal on change. Here is a jsfiddle for the same http://jsfiddle.net/ravikumaranantha/Sb6zS/3/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Product 1</td>
        <td>
            <input class="quantity" type="text" value="10" />
            <input class="price" type="hidden" value="20" />
        </td>
        <td>$20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Product 1</td>
        <td>
            <input class="quantity" type="text" value="20" />
            <input class="price" type="hidden" value="40" />
        </td>
        <td>$40</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="subtotal"></div>


$('.quantity').on('change', function(){

    var subtotal = 0;
    $('.quantity').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var quantity = parseInt($this.val());
        var price = parseFloat($this.siblings('.price').val())
        subtotal+=quantity*price;
    })
    $('.subtotal').text(subtotal);

})
$('.quantity').trigger('change')
```

Comment: `$this.siblings` is not working, I got `undefinded` error when using it.

Comment: did you miss adding hidden field with price value? `<input class="price" type="hidden" value="40" />` at the same td which has quantity? if you added somewhere else change jQuery selector accordingly.

Comment: Please have a look at my second image uploaded dear, I follow your answer then I got that result, the `qty` in console did not change on `keychange` of the `qty` textbox.

Comment: @Domo in my code `subtotal+=quantity*price;` and subtotal defined outside each. in your code `subTotal = qty * price;` I am incrementing subtotal for every product in list, you are just resetting

Answer (score 1):

i just quickly write a simple http://jsfiddle.net/player889/3PRZr/ . Hope this may help you

```
$(function() {
  $('#B').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#b').text ($('#B').val() *6) ;
}).keyup(function(){
    $("#subtotal").text( $('#A').val() *5 + $('#B').val() *6);
});

$('#A').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#a').text ($('#A').val() *5) ;
  }).keyup(function(){
    $("#subtotal").text( $('#A').val() *5 + $('#B').val() *6);
 });
});

A : <input type="text" id="A"/> x5 
<div id="a"></div>
B : <input type="text" id="B"/> x 6
<div id="b"></div>
sum: <div id="subtotal"></div>
```